# how to put image on normal?

Tags: texturing, normals, normal-map

I'm trying to put the JBL logo on stereo normal, I've tried using texture paint but it doesn't work
[image]

how to make PNG image blending with the normal

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want... Do you want to project the pic on the right onto your box without distortion?

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear. If you want to project the texture have a look here [YT: Blender 2.8 Bake camera mapped projected texture tutorial](https://youtu.be/8NYNiayHvJI)

Comment: i'm sorry if the question isn't clear. so for the stereo texture i'm using normal, and i want to put the JBL png onto the normal and has the normal texture too as the picture on the right side shown...

Comment: Please [edit] any information that will assist in clarifying question, into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I don't think you can blend the logo with a *Normal* map only.

You want to paint the logo on the threads of the fabric/cover and mask out the holes. For this, you need a ***Height*** or ***Displacement*** texture that has the info where the holes are.

For the example, I used the *Displacement* and the *Roughness* textures of [this fabric](https://cc0textures.com/view?id=Fabric038). Got [the logo](https://www.logolynx.com/topic/jbl), inverted the colors, then painted it with the *Stencil* mode of the brush on a new texture. For the *Math* node which is used to mask the logo, I've inverted the colors (**logo=white=1**, **background=black=0**). Of course, you can just use an *Invert* node before the *Math* node.

Once the *Image Texture* nodes are set up, you can mix the logo with the *Mix RBG* node and mask the logo with a *Math* node (mode: *Multiply*). The *Color Ramp* controls the opacity of the "paint"/logo. The *Displacement* texture (black & white) is used for the mixed color because plain white still looks too strong. You can use another Color Ramp to colorize the logo.

[image: Shader setup]
<sup>Shader setup to mix logo and fabric</sup>

The *Normal* texture is omitted from the example since there is already the *Displacement* texture and the images are big. The *Bump* node does the job.

[image: result]
<sup>The box with the material and a LED light</sup>

**Update:** After I had a closer look at the material, it looks more like hard plastic with holes in it than a fabric. In this case, you can get away with just an image that has dots on it.

The logo has now an extra UV map. So you don't need an extra texture and no need to paint it.

The image with dots can be used for the Roughness and Specular slots. Mask the holes with *Color Ramps* and you can create little black holes. (With the *Alpha* slot they even can become transparent).

[image: final model]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution!! but i'm facing another problem. how to stretch the logo without ruining the normal texture on UV editing

Comment: you're welcome! Create a new UV map just for the logo (cover area) then you can scale and move it around. Have a look at the blend file.

Comment: I copy the nodes exactly like what you did but the JBL logo doesn't wanna appear, or did i miss something?

Comment: Do you have both UV maps? There are 2 in the sample file. Check them the *UV Editor* workspace. You can switch them on the right side (Object Data Properties), one is the default UV map and the other one is for the logo

Comment: thank you so much!! you help a lot!^^